# Handle button click in gridview in combination with rowclick

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my asp.net application. We've added code to intercept row clicks anywhere on a row.

This works perfectly. Whenever a row is clicked, the `RowCommand`event is fired.
(in this case it redirects the user to a different page)

Now I want to add a column with an Image which, when clicked, should not redirect the user, but fire some Javascript. 
However, while the javascript is fired, the RowClick is also fired.
Is there a way to temporarily disable the RowClick?

Edit: Updated code

The gridview:

```
<asp:GridView  id="OpleidingView" runat="server" SkinID="sknGridView" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="OPLEIDING_ID, OPLEIDING_OMSCHRIJVING, EIGENAAR">
    <Columns>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_OMSCHRIJVING"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_COLO_CODE"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_COHORT"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_CODE"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_VERSIE"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_LEERWEG"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_NIVEAU"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="OPLEIDING_VERWIJDERD"></asp:BoundField>    
        <asp:templatefield>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgDelen" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The Javascript function:

```
function Test()
{
    alert("hi");
    return false;
}
```

The RowDataBound event:

```
Protected Sub OpleidingView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles OpleidingView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me.OpleidingView, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ID = "Disable" & e.Row.RowIndex.ToString          

        Dim img As Image = CType(e.Row.FindControl("imgdelen"), Image)
        img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/DefaultTheme/delen_zwart.png"
        img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Test();")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: return false from your img click function..

Comment: My javascript is this: function Test()
                {
                    alert("hi");
                    return false;
                } , yet it still fires the rowclick

Comment: and show how do you call it?

Comment: img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Test();")

Comment: img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Test();") .. try this

Comment: Unfortunately the RowClick is still fired.

Comment: show you full source code.